# I want to design a field for a 4-in-a-row game

Tags: android, xml, layout, imageview

I'm trying to set up a 4-in-a-row Game and have a little problem and can't fix it! This is my code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".Names" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="7" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="7" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="7" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="7" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="7" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="7" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/feld_leer" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and this appears on the screen:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39774761/Unbenannt.PNG

Can somebody help me with making these small white strokes disappear?

Comment: The XML is correct. How does the image look like? Is it a blue square? Why don't you make the background blue and take only a white circle.

Answer (score 1):

your circles are not perfectly similar. Since you are using the same image for every circle, I suspect, that the last row got scaled down to `fitXY`.

Maybe you want to try a [GridView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use weights along with `wrap_content` in the same dimension. It doesn't make sense. For each of these:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="7" >
```

Use this instead:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="7" >
```

Or alternatively use a fixed width.